# Jinja2 variable (string) not being printed if surrounded by {{ delimiter }}

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a macro in jinja2 that was working perfectly up until I tried to pass a string to it that looks something like this `/test/{{ vehicle.id }}`. The string printed to the page is `/test/`.

The string is coming from a database, so I'm a little confused what's happening. It's like jinja is trying to parse the string and replace the values (which is actually what I'm trying to accomplish), but it's failing and ripping the expression out instead. I tried passing the vehicle dict to the macro as well to see if it would 'just work', but no dice. I thought if maybe I had `vehicle` available to the context it would work without much effort on my part.

Here's some simple sample code:

```
# Assume db_values.url is set to '/test/{{ vehicle.id }}'
{% macro banner(db_values, vehicle={}) %}
  <a href="{{ db_values.url }}"></a>
{% endmacro %}
```

And where I'm calling it:

```
# Assume vehicle = { 'id': '1' }
{{ vehicle.id }}
{{ db_values }}
<div class="banner-link">
  {{ banner(db_values, vehicle) }}
</div>
```

And this is what's being outputted to the page:

```
1
{u'url': u'/test/'}
<div class="banner-link">
  <a href="/test/"></a>
</div>
```

Hitting mongodb directly in terminal responds with:

```
{ 'url': 'test/{{ vehicle.id }}' }
```

Anybody else run into something like this before? Basically what I'm trying to do is allow somebody in an admin interface to use *tokens* in the url that are replaced at runtime based on the context of the page. Seems simple enough, but jinja keeps stripping it.

Comment: Have you tried printing `db_values.url` or `db_values` to make sure it has the correct content?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot to add that into the question. I'll update the question with that info.

Comment: Can you show us how you populate db_values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this on my own. The reason my database value had the {{ vehicle.id }} syntax in it is because I wanted to jinja to parse it. So when jinja wasn't parsing it (probably because of a context issue), I took to a custom filter and I'm happily on my way.

Here's the gist of it:

#### Jinja2 Filter

```
from jinja2 import Environment

def replace_tokens(url, vehicle):
  if url is not None:
    url = Environment().from_string(url).render({ 'vehicle': vehicle })
  return url
```

#### Macro

```
# Assume db_values.url is set to '/test/{{ vehicle.id }}'
{% macro banner(db_values, vehicle={}) %}
  <a href="{{ db_values.url | replace_tokens(vehicle) }}"></a>
{% endmacro %}
```